# Only apply disabled to one input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, input

How can I use the 'id' to only apply the disabled/enabled button if a check box is clicked to ONLY the second button, as I need it to toggle on and off depending on if a checkbox is clicked or not. Where as the first button will always be on

http://jsfiddle.net/BPhZe/2122/

```
    <h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>

<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="sub1" value="Do thing">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="here" id="option-12"> <label for="option-2">Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="now" id="option-22"> <label for="option-2">Option 4</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="sub2" value="Do thing" disabled="true">
    </div>
</form>

var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `id` of the second submit button instead of `input[type='submit']`.

```
var submitButt = $("#sub2");
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tg0wvkwj/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt2 = $("#sub2");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt2.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```